# How to create a paginated grid where all data is google indexable?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, seo, kendo-grid, googlebot

**What's a good technique to creating a paginated HTML/js/jQuery data grid where each page is easily crawl-able by google?**

I know I need to start out with an HTML grid and then use *progressive enhancement* to turn it into something with javascript (once the page is loaded, then something like [jqgrid's tableToGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atable_to_jqgrid) or [kendo UI grid's initialization from table](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/from-table.html) will update the HTML to a nice javascript grid). So I'm comfortable knowing the first page of the grid can be read by google, since it's loaded in HTML first. But what about the pagination? Do I need to load a paginated HTML set of links, then hide those page numbers once the progressive enhancement loads the javascript grid? And how do I ensure google will scan each page of the paginated links? (consider that in typical paginated links, only so many page numbers are shown along with a "next page" or "previous page" link).

Also note, each page on the grid will be represented with a &page parameter in the URL. However, I don't want to simply rely on sites from around the web directly linking to pages for google to index the data. Can I not have google be aware of all the pages without waiting for others to directly link to each page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for a successful progressive enhancement (SEO friendly) solution, I ended up using jqgrid ([Jqgrid & progressive enhancement: Successfully progresses from HTML, to local JSON, to remote JSON, but pager doesn't start correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824991/jqgrid-progressive-enhancement-successfully-progresses-from-html-to-local-js/22827448#22827448)) and I also insert an HTML version of paging so that search engines can follow the links and retrieve additional data as well.

Answer (score 0):

Easily crawl-able is up to the content. But if you're worried by Google finding the pages try adding them to the sitemap. Also if you have your "Next ->" button and/or pagination links to specific pages in a way that your users will find them easily Google will too.